# How do I solve this mixed enum equatable thing?

Tags: swift, enums, equatable

I have this

```
enum MyEnum {
  case one
  case two
}
```

and this

```
var array:[MyEnum] = [.one]
```

and later

```
func add(_ case:MyEnum) {
  if array.contains(case) { return }
  array.append(case)
}
```

So far so good.

Then I have added a third option to the enum

```
enum MyEnum {
  case one
  case two
  case three(user:User)
}
```

then the line

```
if array.contains(case) { return }
```

is giving this error

```
Referencing instance method 'contains' on 'Sequence' requires that 'MyEnum' conform to 'Equatable'
```

I guess that the problem is this

1. `contains` can easily see if `.one` is equal to `.two` or not, so it can check if these elements are on `array`.
2. `contains` cannot easily see if `.three(user:"bob")` is the same as `.three(user:"carl")`, right?

I don't care which user is, I just want to compare if `array` has an entry `three` or not.

If the `array` is `[.two, .one, .three(user:"bob)]` and I try to append `.three("user:"carl")` I want the line `if array.contains(.three("user:"carl"))`to return true.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is `User` equatable? If it is, just conform `MyEnum` to `Equatable` and you are done.

Comment: BRILLIANT. I hate when Xcode does not say the real reason behind the issues. Thanks. Please make this an answer.

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed, but I would have created maybe a `isOfSameType(_:)` instead on `MyEnum`, since it's supposed to return true even if the User is different. It depends if later the user needs a more "usual equatable".

Comment: @Larme - can you explain that with code? Sorry, I am new to this equatable thing.

Comment: @Larme's comment made me realise that I misread the question. See the second dupe for how to compare enums without considering their associated values, and use that to conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QwjGTanZ